# issue with boost::tokenizer_iterator -- how to peek next iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

The code is something like so

```
 void buildIt(Object& o, Tokenizer::const_iterator begin, Tokenizer::const_iterator end){
   if(begin == end) return;
   else{
    string parent = *begin;
    bool hasChild = (begin+1) != end; //error: class booost::token_iterator<...> has no member named 'advance'
   }
 }
```

How can I check to see if the next iterator is valid without moving it?

Comment: Your problem is the `begin+1`. This operation is only supported on RandomAccessIterators. In general, try to avoid using it. Either use `boost::next`/`boost::prev` or `std::advance`. Depending if you want to change the state of the iterator.

Comment: I thought it would use its version of std::advance in that case depending on iterator type?

Comment: No, advance is going to use the right method depending on iterator type, not `operator+`.

Comment: ok cool, was just confused because I was expecting the operator+ to invoke advance or something similar. That and the error message said it couldn't find advance when using the operator+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just copy the iterator and increment the copy. Or use `boost::next`.

```
if(boost::next(iter) == end)
  cout << "...";
```

Comment: I guess that is a little better. Maybe the newer boost version fixed this issue

Comment: I guess its not an issue but more of a misunderstanding on my part about the interface

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Tokenizer::const_iterator i = begin; i!= end; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: is there no way without the for-loop? I just need to check element after begin, without making a function or that for-loop, there has to be a cleaner way?

Comment: A description to go along with the code would be helpful to more than just the original author of the question.

Comment: @Boeckm my bad, hehe, I thought the for loop itself is clear enough.